# delete rows from multiple tables CONSTRAINT ERROR

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to erase information from two tables simultaneously that are connected with each other but not I am able to give me this error:

> Can not delete or update a row parent: a foreign key constraint fails (`socios`.`pagamentos`,`CONSTRAINT FK_FOREIGN KEY (`nrSocio`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BSJl.png)

Comment: first delete from independent row

Comment: Delete from the child (referencing) table first then the parent last

Comment: Could you list some of the libraries or stack you are using? JDBC? JPA?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your table design and make the relation `delete cascade`. In this case the child rows will be deleted automatically.

Or you could delete the records in a single statement like this

```
delete c, p
from parent_table p
left join child_table c on p.id = c.parent_id
where p.id = 1
```

Comment: The table has the people and the other table has information of all people, only when delete the person I want to delete the information of that person in the other table

Answer (score 0):

If you delete from parent table,data in child tablr will not be able to refer parent table. This is why till thereare is a referrence ib child table, you can't delete from parent table. There are few ways to get rid of this situation.

1. Delete data from child table and then delete from parent  table
2. You can use delete cascade relation in your table.
    In this case, whenever you will delete data from parent table, data in child table will also be deleted.
3. The foreign key constraint can be removed to delete which is not a good approach.